# Possible to insert an existing page into another VMA structure?

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, kernel

I`ve been learning the linux kernel through some experiments.Recently i m wondering whether it is possible to share pages between two user-space processes by inserting the pages of one process into the vma structure of the other one, after the latter calls mmap and sends the addr back to kernel through netlink.The insertion would be done in a driver module.The reason for this test,is that the two processes might not be directly communicating with each other,and duplicate pages of read-only memory could be a bad choice considering efficiency and redundancy.

And after some research I found the vm_insert_page function and the traditional remap_pfn_range. However It says in the lxr:

/**
2020  * vm_insert_page - insert single page into user vma

2021  * @vma: user vma to map to

2022  * @addr: target user address of this page

2023  * @page: source kernel page

2024  *

2025  * This allows drivers to insert individual pages they've allocated

2026  * into a user vma.

2027  *

2028  * **The page has to be a nice clean *individual* kernel allocation**."

[from lxr](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/memory.c?v=3.2#L2041)

Does this mean it`s impossible to insert an existing page into another vma?The function can Only be called with newly created pages?I always thought pages could be sharing with a reference count number.

Comment: I think there is no function in the Linux kernel to exactly satisfy your requirement. But do_mmap_pgoff() function in kernel is first searching whether there is already one page cache existing by traverse the address_space which related to the file, if existing, it will share the page cache in the current process vma structure. So if one want to do the similar feature, one can following the do_mmap_pgoff() function approach.